# Data with date range, need to report annually by month

Tags: sql, aggregate

I am working on a data set that has pre-payment data for a list of services. The structure is: name, service, start of service (date), termination of service (date).

I need to report on this data annually, for each month, answering the question: for a given service and month, how many people are prepaid? The result will be inclusive, meaning that if a name and service combination hits a month for 1 or more days, they are reported on.

What is the best way to approach this using SQL or a SQL variant?

Thanks!

Sample Input and Output data below:

IN:
`Name,Service,Start,End
jon,a,05/12/2018,08/26/2018
paul,b,06/05/2018,08/08/2018
michael,a,02/18/2018,08/15/2018
mary,a,04/22/2018,10/14/2018
jonas,b,05/10/2018,07/02/2018
thomas,a,08/05/2018,10/18/2018
jessica,c,03/09/2018,07/16/2018
arthur,c,02/03/2018,03/15/2018
hugo,c,06/07/2018,09/01/2018
larry,a,11/23/2018,12/20/2018
nick,b,08/23/2018,11/22/2018
beth,c,09/20/2018,12/25/2018
ashley,a,04/14/2018,05/19/2018
tim,a,01/05/2018,05/26/2018
allan,b,06/28/2018,12/11/2018
jeffrey,b,03/04/2018,04/22/2018
steven,b,01/20/2018,06/07/2018
dawn,c,06/15/2018,10/14/2018
brandy,b,09/01/2018,10/08/2018
christine,a,04/15/2018,07/31/2018`

OUT:
`Service,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec
a,1,2,2,5,6,4,4,4,2,2,1,1
b,1,1,2,2,2,4,3,3,3,3,2,1
c,0,1,2,1,1,3,3,2,3,2,1,1`

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I can use SQL Server or Vertica, sticky bit

Comment: Yes, D-Shih. I am working on a sample set/result.

Comment: Sample data added in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use conditional aggregation. For the year 2018 that may look like:

```
SELECT [service],
       count(DISTINCT
             CASE
               WHEN [start] < '2018-02-01'
                     OR [end] >= '2018-01-01' THEN
                [name]
             END) [jan],
       count(DISTINCT
             CASE
               WHEN [start] < '2018-03-01'
                     OR [end] >= '2018-02-01' THEN
                [name]
             END) [feb],
       ...
       count(DISTINCT
             CASE
               WHEN [start] < '2019-01-01'
                     OR [end] >= '2018-12-01' THEN
                [name]
             END) [dec]
       FROM [elbat]
       GROUP BY [service];
```

I assume, that you want the distinct count of people (count a person only once, even if they appear multiple times). If this is not true, remove the `DISTINCT`s.

I further assumed, that you want to count, if the service period just overlaps the month. If you want to count only, if the period is completely contained in a month change the conditions to:

```
[start] >= <first of month>
AND [end] < <first of next month>
```

(Replace `<first of month>` and `<first of next month>`.)

By the way, that the people are given by their names is a bad idea. How do you know, if it's one person or more, if there are more "John Smith"s?

Comment: Agreed with the naming comment. The name isn't reported on and is codified in the actual implementation.
I need to create an annual report, subdivided by month and service. I have added a sample set to reflect my desired result. Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: @AndrewGlenn: I edit the answer according to your edit.

Comment: Thanks, sticky bit. I appreciate it.  :)